# How to intersect lines and polygons in R?

Tags: geoprocessing, r

Following on from [an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/divide-vector-in-equal-smaller-parts-in-qgis-or-similar) about intersecting polygons with lines to chop up a polygon into smaller **polygon** units (in QGIS), I wanted to try the same thing in R. However, I cannot seem to find a method that works!

`over()` doesn't have a method for polygons intersecting with lines; I found `gIntersection()` from rgeos but it fails:

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)

poly <- readShapePoly("polygon.shp")
lines <- readShapeLines("lines.shp")

chopped <- gIntersection(poly, lines)
```

Giving:

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, "rgeos_intersection") : 
  UnsupportedOperationException: GeometryGraph::add(Geometry *): unknown geometry type: N4geos4geom18GeometryCollectionE
```

**Update**: [Here's a link to the files](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3451554/intersects.zip) in question.

**Update 2**: PaulG notes that it works and after updating rgeos and R I got rid of the error above. Thanks PaulG ...

However, gIntersection results in a SpatialLines object no matter whether I put in (poly, lines) or (lines, poly) - whereas the operation I did in QGIS (or Arc, back in the bad ol' days) will divide a polygon with the lines and result in a *polygon* object, not line.

So, how do I chop up my polygon with the lines and get *polygons* out?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you could post a copy of the shape files in question so we could run our own tests. Btw, is maptools loaded, too?

Comment: I have found `rgeos::gIntersection()` to also be quite fussy about the nature of the `Spatial*` object you pass it.  I have also solved very cryptic error messages from this function by using the `byid=TRUE` parameter.  Not sure if this will work in your case.

Comment: @R.K. - yes, maptools also loaded; have updated with link to files.

Comment: @PaulG: tried it with byid=TRUE also with no success.

Comment: It likely comes down to the format of your `Spatial*` object.  Try producing a `SpatialLines` and a `SpatialPolygons` object from first principles and compare what you have there to the object you load using `readShapePoly()`.  It could be something like IDs are not continuous, or hole attributes.

Comment: @Simbamangu I just used your files to run the above script, and I found that the line should be changed to: `poly <- readShapePoly("poly.shp")`.  There are no files `polygon.*` in the zip you provided. It then worked for me, performing the intersection as expected.  Could the error be as simple as loading the wrong shape file?  (I am using `rgeos` package version 0.2-1 under R 2.14.2)

Comment: @PaulG - no, I just renamed it incorrectly when I archived the files; it's polygon.shp on mine, so that's not it. I'm going to try your suggestion to try building some shapes directly (these were made by QGIS) or use another source, see what I get.

Comment: @PaulG - after carefully re-reading your comments, discovered I was on rgeos 0.1-5 and updated everything (R to 2.15 / rgeos to 0.2-5). gIntersection works, but not as I'd like (see edit above).

Comment: @Simbamangu it doesn't seem that `gIntersection()` will really do what you want.  If your lines, forming a grid, were polygonized, it might work, but this is probably not what you want.  I suggest asking this either on StackOverflow where more spatial R folks hang out, or on the R-sig-geo list where you'll reach the architects of `rgeos` and related tools.

Comment: I usually intersect polygons and lines with qgis and it's very fast. Using R, today i'm trying to intercept a sp object with 24500 lines with another sp object, a gridpolygon. The process started at 19:12 LT and now it's 20:08 and it's still dosent finish. This are the commands from [here](http://rfunctions.blogspot.com.br/). library(rgdal) library(raster) library(rgeos) library(dismo) ingrid <- intersect(mylines, gridpolygon) I'm not sure if it will help, i'm looking for a similar command in R, but it takes too much time. You could try [@johanvdw answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23973/1

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [RSAGA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSAGA/index.html). I'm not too familiar with it myself, but the command would be something like:

```
rsaga.geoprocessor("libshapes_polygons", "Polygon-Line Intersection", list(POLYGONS="polygonshape.shp",LINES="lineshape.shp",INTERSECT="result.shp"))
```

Comment: This looks like it might help, but it's really troublesome to install (lots of dependencies and downloads); will try it out though.

Comment: Do you have to do the intersection in R? You could just do the intersection in saga and import again afterwards. Anyway, only 2 downloads should be needed for RSAGA: install.packages("RSAGA") and then saga itself.

Comment: I have other options for doing the intersection (QGIS) but would like to be able to have this available in R. Installing 'saga itself' is the troublesome bit I mention above - OSX has no easy binary install!

Answer (score 4):

I've been facing the same problem several times. I'will focus on two methods that works for me

1) The **intersect** function from raster package. It returns a SpatialLinesDataframe including the **id** of each polygon.

```
library(raster)
newLines <- raster::intersect(SpatialLinesDataframe, SpatialPolygonDataframe)
```

2) Calling QGIS from R with the package **RQGIS**, as showed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/209552/18535) I think that this method is faster than several other, but you have to take care with the qgis version. Here is the [github](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS) of the creator. Also, with this package you can use any of the geoalgoritm from qgis.

```
library(RQGIS)    
qgis_env <- set_env("PATH")
params <- get_args_man(alg = "qgis:intersection", 
                           qgis_env = qgis_env)
params$INPUT <- line_1
params$INPUT2 <- poly_1
out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:intersection",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

EDIT in 2018: I was thinking and you polygon with another polygon, to get smaller polygons: Take a look of [this](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_ops.html) link for the Manual of the new sf R package (Pebesma, 2018).

- Edzer Pebesma (2018). sf: Simple Features for R. R package version
  0.6-3. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sf
- Pebesma, E., 2018. Simple Features for R: Standardized Support for Spatial1995 Vector Data. The R Journal.

Comment: Interesting ... however, (1) results in _lines_, which isn't what I'm after (want to chop up a polygon into smaller polygons); (2) fails with "Error in sys.excepthook", will keep trying though.

Comment: Maybe an intersection between your original polygon and another polygon formed with your lines would chop your original polygon

Comment: Simbamangu, (1) does what you want. The info is stored in newLines$id (where id is the identifier of your polygon features). So if you subset yourPolygon[newLines$id, ] you get exactly the features of the polygon that are touched by the spatialLine.