# Error in dirname(x) RQGIS

Tags: qgis, r

I'm trying to intercept SpatialLinesDataFrame (170 fields and 140000 lines) with a SpatialPolygonDataFrame using RQGIS.I'm following the instruction from [github](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS). I modified the ../processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py files accordingly. My lines and polygon have numeric dataframes.

I'm running the following code:

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(RQGIS)
setwd("/data/opera/sergio")

load("data/out/network/lines.rda") #lines
load("data/out/network/g.rda") #polygon
dir_tmp <- "/home/sergio"
my_env <- set_env()
params <- get_args_man(alg = "qgis:intersection", 
                       qgis_env = my_env)
params$INPUT <- lines
params$INPUT2 <- g
params$OUTPUT <- file.path(dir_tmp, "COg.shp")

system.time(out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:intersection",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = my_env))

Error in dirname(x) : a character vector argument expected
my_env
$root
[1] "/usr"

$qgis_prefix_path
[1] "/usr/bin/qgis"

$python_plugins
[1] "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins"
```

How to fix: **Error in dirname(x) : a character vector argument expected**?

Comment: would be helped by a reproducible example

Comment: i know, but the results are part of a paper, if I upload the files, i'm afraid i would have some issues or complications

Comment: You can anonymize your data; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some advice on how to do so

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with Michael in that a reproducible example would really help! Anyways, let us create a spatial line and polygon object:

```
library("dplyr")
library("sp")
# construct coordinates for a polygon and a line object
coords_1 <- matrix(data = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                   ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
coords_2 <- cbind(c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.4), c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6))
# convert the coordinates into spatial objects
poly_1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords_1)), 1))) %>%
  as(., "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
line_1 <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(coords_2)), 1)))
line_1 <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(line_1, data.frame(dummy = 1))
# visualize
plot(poly_1)
plot(line_1, col = "lightblue", add = TRUE)
```

Now the question is what you would like to do. There are two ways how you can intersect polygons and lines. The first would be to intersect the line object with the polygons. The second option is to intersect the polygon object with the line object. Unfortunately, the QGIS help (`open_help("qgis:intersection")`) does not clarify this. This leaves us with the trial-and-error approach.

```
qgis_env <- set_env("C:/OSGeo4W64/")
params <- get_args_man(alg = "qgis:intersection", 
                       qgis_env = qgis_env)
params$INPUT <- poly_1
params$INPUT2 <- line_1
params$OUTPUT <- "intersection.shp"
out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:intersection",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = qgis_env)
```

This produces no output and following error:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile
```

This indicates that `INPUT2` probably should not be a line object. Ok, so let's reverse the inputs:

```
params$INPUT <- line_1
params$INPUT2 <- poly_1
out <- run_qgis(alg = "qgis:intersection",
                params = params,
                load_output = params$OUTPUT,
                qgis_env = qgis_env)
plot(out, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

Ok, this works, and means that QGIS lets you intersect lines with polygons. However, if you want to intersect polygons with lines, check out e.g., `saga:polygonlineintersection`:

```
args <- get_args_man(alg = "saga:polygonlineintersection", qgis_env = qis_env)
args$POLYGONS <- poly_1
args$LINES <- line_1
args$INTERSECT <- "poly_int.shp"
out <- run_qgis(alg = "saga:polygonlineintersection",
                params = args,
                load_output = args$INTERSECT,
                qgis_env = qgis_env)
```