# How can I automatically split a spatial layer to a grid

Tags: qgis, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Divide vector in equal smaller parts in QGIS or similar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/divide-vector-in-equal-smaller-parts-in-qgis-or-similar)

I am a software engineer and the company I work for has a project that needs some spatial data manipulation in order to provide routes to users. The client has provided me the spatial layer through a Microsoft SQL Server 2008, encoded as geometry polygons. The table is as:
zone_id (int), zone_geometry (geometry).

In order to make the routing algorithm more precise, I need to split each zone in tiles, so I thought that I need to divide the each zone to a grid.

Is there an automated way to do this?

Are there any references or any wiki for what I need?

I have no previous experience with GIS.