# How to Split a vector file into several different files using a Grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, splitting

I have a shapefile containing contour for a large area, and I want to split it into different shapefiles each covering a 1KM X 1KM area.
I have already created the required Grid shapefile in QGIS.  How do I now split the contours using the created Grid?

I am searching for something equivalent to the [Split Tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Split_%28Analysis%29) in ArcGIS.

Comment: There are three questions (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38973 & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25357) but they have to with splitting shapes in one file itself, and not splitting into several different files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried first making an intersection with the grid layer and then using `Vector -> Data managment tools -> Split vector layer`? It sounds exactly like what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by loading the shapefile you want to split into Qgis then load the Grid shapefile and use `vector->Geoprocessing Tools->Clip`

Select the shapefile to split as the "input vector layer" and the Grid shapefile as "Clip layer"

The resulting shapefile will be your source shapefile clipped to the polygons in the Grid Shapefile, you can then select different clipped shapes to save to different shapefiles via `Layer->Save selection as vector file`