# How to split polygon into equal segments in QGIS?

Tags: polygon, splitting, qgis-2.12

I try to split polygon layer into equal length segments of 1000m:

[image]

The attribute table of the layer is:

[image]

I have read those links but didn't find a solution to my question:

[How to split a vector in equal smaller parts in QGIS or similar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/how-to-split-a-vector-in-equal-smaller-parts-in-qgis-or-similar)

[How to split an irregular polygon into equal areas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43769/how-to-split-an-irregular-polygon-into-equal-areas)

I also tried to use "split vector layer" function but didn't get desirable answer.

I also tried to find the "Polygon Splitter" (in this link [polygon split with predefined area](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185797/polygon-split-with-predefined-area)) plugin but I didn't find it in the Plugin list.

Comment: Personally, i would do things this way since what you have seems to be mostly linear. Create points to help you see where your polygons will be cut. I'd do this by Skeletonizing said polygons, i think have tools inside the SAGA toolbox via QGIS that might help you out for this, then using a plugin like Qchainage to create point every 1000 meter. That should be a good start, afterwards you'll have more options to split thoses polygons if you know where they should be cut. (Like creating lines at 90° from the skeleton and then using thoses to split your shapes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Plugin named "Divide Polygon"- it can cut the polygon into equal parts. The parts defined by polygon's area.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the Plugin is **Polygon Splitter** which splits polygons into equal area parts. The Plugin is marked as experimental, therefore, you need to enable "Show also experimental plugins" from the settings as shown below

[image]

Here is the plugin after enabling "Show also experimental plugins"

[image]

Comment: the plug don't work- the compute stucked- i get an error

Comment: I didn't test the plugin before, I showed you how to find the plugin. What the error says? Please update your question and show the error.

Comment: the computer just stucked and i have to turn off the QGIS

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using [Grass v.split](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.split.html) in the processing toolbox. I just accomplished this in QGIS 3 by typing in a segment length with an input line layer and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This only works for lines, not polygons...