# Dividing polygon in equal parts, number of parts as attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, splitting

I have a polygon layer. Each polygon is part of a street, so it's not straight or all the same orientation. Each single polygon has an attribute with a number.

I would like to divide the polygons in equal parts (same area, or even better: same length of longest side). The number of parts is an attribute. So for instance, some polygons should be divided by 1 (so they stay the same), some in 2 parts, some in 10 parts, etc.

This parting should always be in the 'long' side: The street should be divided length-wise. Is this possible?

Example input:
[image]

Example output:
[image]

Comment: Could be useful: [1] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/how-to-split-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-in-qgis-3 [2] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201100/how-to-split-polygon-into-equal-segments-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to make a model to do this with a single press of a button. I made it myself. It's quite difficult with a lot of steps, but check the following printscreens:

Model:
[image]

Origin shape:
[image]

Export shape:
[image]

Edit:
The model for download, link below:
https://trajan-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ruben_trajan_nl/EZmV6W6dTe9Dt0FHzZSITwwBdPJ-BpUqtwuI_Ls6YkUalw?e=ElC6vD

I also saved the model as Script. Download link below:
https://trajan-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ruben_trajan_nl/EVo9WxDuFLdIpY-_NN6MrhUBuY2LT_2JiAcTnaB2El_Weg?e=p9RdoW
There are a couple of places where you probably would need to make changes.

- For example the fields that are necessary right now are 'ID' and 'Capaciteit'.
- The length of the vertices (so the max width of the polygons) is currently set to 12 meters, so 6 meters to each side from the center.
- The percentage overlap between the polygon and the bounding box need to be more than 50% currently. I have tested with multiple variations.

This can all be changed.

Comment: Nicely done! Can you also provide this model as script, so others can make use of it. Thanks

Comment: Ok, see edit. I saved as script and uploaded to Onedrive.

Comment: @Trajan Very impressive! Can you also provide this model in a .model file format, thanks.

Comment: Ok, added in the above answer.

Comment: Hey. does it work to divide an area into only two? Not sure if you use the "Voronoi - Polygone" cause it requires at leadt tree points and I just have two in my case https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428067/dividing-a-polygon-into-only-two-equal-areas-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to know the answer for your precise question. But there exists a Plugin that you can divide bottom-down or left-right, it is called [Polygon Divider](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Submission/). But it your case it does not help fully.

Comment: I kind of got it working. I made a model in the model designer that works for the most polygons.