# Dividing a polygon into only two equal areas in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-processing, splitting, equal-area

I would like to look at only 50% of the area. To do this, I would like to divide the surface into two equal areas. (Afterwards, I would like to automate it using the model builder).
I have followed this tutorial:

[Splitting polygon into equal area polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/splitting-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-using-qgis)

https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/06/12/split-polygons-qgis/

At the point where the application "Voronoi - Polygone" is executed I fail, because this requires at least tree points. But since I need only two surfaces, I have only two points.
Does anyone have another idea? Or knows how I can work around my problem?

[image: Polygon Area]