# Splitting / Divide Polygon in same squares

Tags: postgis, polygon, function, splitting

I have a polygon in a table with 100 meters to 100 meters ( 1 row) and I would like to splitt / devide it to same square parts for 10 meters. The result should be then 100 rows with 10x10 meters. How can I do this? Is there any function or Select in PostGIS?

Comment: You can use QGIS split fonction as it's explain [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23688/how-to-split-a-vector-in-equal-smaller-parts-in-qgis-or-similar)

Comment: You can use the function ST_CreateFishnet or ST_OffsetCurve in PostGIS, as you prefer...